# Combine tabnew and ls in vim

Tags: linux, vim, ls

When I need to open a file in a new tab in vim, I do `:tabnew relativepath/filename`. I find it difficult to hunt for files from `tabnew`. It does auto-completion and it even cycles through items in a directory upon pressing the Tab key, but it would be really nice to have a way to list all the files in the directory, like with `ls` from tabnew. Is this possible? How?

Or, how do you go about opening a file in a new tab, when you don't exactly recall the path to the file?

Today, I `Ctrl-Z` to the terminal, use `ls` or `grep` to find the file, get the path, go back to vim, and then  open the file... I guess there is a better way..

Comment: Are you aware that you can "edit" directories to get listings and navigate?  See ":help netrw.txt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With `:set wildmenu`, a list of file names will be shown above the command-line once you trigger completion; it is updated as you cycle through the candidates. This is the closest built-in mechanism to your question. 
   If you choose this route, I recommend to also adapt the related `'wildmode'` to suit your needs, e.g. 
   `set wildmode=list:longest,full`
- You don't need to leave Vim to execute `ls`, you can launch from Vim: `:!ls`
- You can browse the file system from Vim itself. The *netrw* plugin is built-in (you can trigger this e.g. via `:tabedit relativepath/`); others prefer *NERD_tree*.

Answer (score -1):

Install gvim. Then you have all the editing capabilies of vim. On a graphically enhanced version of vim. With the ability to open file prompt manager to open new files.

Or instead install "[Sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3)" which might be a stronger text editor for programming with file type recognition.

Comment: no need, entirely doable in vim